# Is it possible to have multiple SSH host aliases?

Tags: ssh

I have a laptop that can obviously be inside or outside of my home network at times. When I need to SSH into a machine inside of my network, the connection is fairly straightforward:

```
localhost $ ssh machinelearning
```

When I'm trying to access the machine from *outside* of my network, I then need to connect to my router, then SSH from there:

```
localhost $ ssh router.mytotallyuniquedomain.com
router $ ssh machinelearning
```

I remember there being a shortcut for doing the latter command in `~/.ssh/config`, but at the moment I can't remember what it is.

Is there a way for me to supply multiple hostnames or types of connections so that when I do this:

```
$ ssh machinelearning
```

SSH will first attempt to connect to the `machinelearning` host in the local network and then attempt to tunnel in through `router.mytotallyuniquedomain.com`, all without me having to type out the long hostname?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't a duplicate as it's specifically asking how to do this from a configuration point of view, namely "how do I proxy connect to a host via a Host directive in `~/.ssh/config?`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Method #1 - ProxyCommand & netcat

I use this setup in my `$HOME/.ssh/config` to facilitate this:

```
Host intserver1-o intserver2-o intserver3-o
    ProxyCommand ssh userR@extserver.mydom.com nc `echo %h|sed 's/-o//'` %p
```

I then can `ssh intserver2-o` from where ever and I get into this internal server. When at home on the LAN I use `ssh intserver1`.

**NOTE:** The trick above requires netcat (`nc`) installed on the extserver1.

#### Method #2 - nested ssh

Alternatively you can use this method as well:

```
$ ssh -t -l gatewayuser gatewayserver "ssh -l serveruser internalserver"
```

You're basically nesting SSH calls in this method.

#### Method #3 - ProxyCommand & ssh -W

With newer versions of SSH (5.4+) you can use `ssh` instead of `nc` via the `-W` switch.

```
Host TARGETHOST
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p PROXYHOST
```

The `%h` & `%p` are macros for the host name port that were used for `TARGETHOST`.

Comment: So only the newer versions of SSH would allow me to configure typing one hostname and mapping to different hostnames internally?

Comment: Not really I'll add that example.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay - I think I'm confusing the gateway switch's existence with `vncviewer` which has a `-via GW` option.

Comment: Why not use the `-W` switch?