# SSH Tunnel with autossh

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-tunneling

I can't seem to find a close enough example but here it goes.

I'm trying to in the end setup `rsync` from one server to another through an `ssh` tunnel. Local (my machine) will run the `rsync` to pull files from a remote server through the `ssh` tunnel.

I can connect with this command:

```
$ ssh -L 1522:localhost:middlemanip:1521 user@server
```

My rsync attempts led me to try this:

```
$ rsync -avz -e "ssh localhost:1522:middlemanip:1521 ssh" \
    user@server:/source /dest/
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I moved to `autossh` where I attempted this:

```
$ autossh -M 1522 -q -f -N -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" \
    -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -L localhost:middlemanip:1521 user@server
```

No luck so far, but there may be a better way to do this then what I have laid out?

Comment: Take a look at the methods I describe here: [Is it possible to have multiple SSH host aliases?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122023/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-ssh-host-aliases/122034#122034)

Comment: Yeah that doesn't really help. Thats the same info that's out there. I'm looking for someone who setup a persistent tunnel to rsync over.

Comment: Those can be used when you invoke your `rsync -e "...."`. I use `autossh` for a persistent tunnel to my IMAP and SMTP servers at home when travelling via my laptop, from what you've described you do not need persistence, only a proxy connection for the duration of the `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this link on SSH ProxyCommand](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html) to be a very useful way to enable SSH proxies. It lets you go from Server --to-->proxy---to-->destination very easily and transparently!